# Filter range on Spree commerce

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, spree

I'm working on a spree commerce application. I have troubles with product filters. I can edit range filters but i want to add "all prices" filter.

Here is the code:

```
conds = [ [ Spree.t(:or_over_price, price: format_price(0)) , v[:amount].gteq(0)],
                  [ "#{format_price(25000)} - #{format_price(50000)}"        , v[:amount].in(25000..50000)],
                  [ "#{format_price(50000)} - #{format_price(75000)}"        , v[:amount].in(50000..75000)],
                  [ "#{format_price(75000)} - #{format_price(100000)}"        , v[:amount].in(75000..100000)]]
        {
```

So is working as **0 or over**. But i want to show it as "all prices"

I need to change this line but i dont know how:

```
[ Spree.t(:or_over_price, price: format_price(0)) , v[:amount].gteq(0)]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How would this differ from a case when none of conditions are selected ? What do you expect when both "all prices" and any of price ranges are selected ?

Comment: It is a radiobutton, it is not deselectable, so you can go back to "none conditions"

Comment: Then if you've altered how price filters are processed (no, change on a view level is not enough), you may use condition which would match all cases, like in your last example, use empty one like `['all', nil]` or do a custom handling in a controller.

Answer (score 1):

Just add to your config/locales/en.yml

```
    all_prices: all prices
```

then in your conds array

```
conds = [ [ Spree.t(:all_prices) , v[:amount].gteq(0)],
              [ "#{format_price(25000)} - #{format_price(50000)}"        , v[:amount].in(25000..50000)],
              [ "#{format_price(50000)} - #{format_price(75000)}"        , v[:amount].in(50000..75000)],
              [ "#{format_price(75000)} - #{format_price(100000)}"        , v[:amount].in(75000..100000)]]
    {
```

Comment: But i want to use or_over_price later. Should i create all_prices then?

Comment: yes, if you want to keep or_over_price, then you should create all_prices.